# Resubscribing happens only after triggering the source observable the second time

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm trying to compose a stream with a send event and an undo event. after sending the message, there is a 3s delay while you can undo the message and return the sent message into the text field. if you started to compose a new message, the sent message should be prepended.

so far I've managed to create the delayed send and undo functionality. the problem occurs, when I send a message, undo it, and then send it again without touching the input, I need to change the value of the input to be able to re-send the message, but cannot resend the restored message.

tried a few workarounds, like dispatching an input event on the textarea, or calling next on the message observable, both in the restore function. none of them worked.

```
textarea.addEventListener('input', event => message$.next(event.target.value))
send.addEventListener('click', () => textarea.value = '')

const sendEvent$ = fromEvent(send, 'click')
const undoEvent$ = fromEvent(undo, 'click')
const message$ = new Subject()
let cache = []

sendEvent$
  .pipe(
    withLatestFrom(message$, (_, m) => m),
    tap(m => cache.push(m)),
    delay(3000),
    takeUntil(undoEvent$.pipe(
      tap(restore)
    )),
    repeatWhen(complete => complete)
  )
  .subscribe(x => {
    console.log(x)
    cache = []
  })

function restore() {
  if (!textarea.value) {
    const message = cache.join('\n')
    textarea.value = message
    cache = []
  }
}
```

link the example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-undo-message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is pretty much there in the restore function. When you restore the "onInput" event doesn't get triggered. So your message queue basically is not enqueued with the restored item. The suggestion given by @webber where you can pass the message$.next(message) is pretty much right and that's what you need to do.

But the problem is how exactly you set it. You can set the value through a setTimeout interval in restore() so that your takeUntil() completes and then the value is enqueued in the Subject

```
function restore() {
  if (!textarea.value) {
    const message = cache.join('\n')
    textarea.value = message
    cache = []
    setTimeout(function(){
      message$.next(message)
    },3000)    
  }
}
```

(or)
You can remove the

```
textarea.addEventListener('input', event => message$.next(event.target.value))
```

and change your send event handler to the following.

```
send.addEventListener('click', () => {
  message$.next(textarea.value);
  textarea.value =''
})
```

Comment: thank you! I had the impression all along that the input event needs to be triggered, your answer made it clear how. this way instead of sendEven$ I can subscribe directly to message$, remove withLatestFrom, sendEvent$ and the textarea listener too. pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

The subscriber works fine, it's just that your `message$` doesn't get updated when the `undoEvent$` triggers. However the value gets set to an empty string.

If you undo, then type and then send again, you will see that it works in the first time as well.

What you have to do is set `message$` to the value of your `textarea` and then it works.

Comment: hey, I've tried to do that in the restore function by calling `message$.next(message)`, if you meant something like this, but didn't change the behaviour. need to set message to the value of cache btw.